# How do I align one navbar item to the right in Bootstrap 5.3 (v5.3.0-alpha1)?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I tried to align a dropdown link in my Bootstrap 5.3 navbar to the right, but I didn't succeed at all. In Bootstrap 3 it was `navbar-right`, in Bootstrap 4 I think it was `ml-auto`, and in Bootstrap 5 beta it was `me-auto`.

I tried
`<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto>`
`<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto>`
`<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto>`
`<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto>`
thinking the item would go to the right end of the navbar, but none of them worked.

Comment: give that specific item that you want to align to the right the class: `ms-auto`. Note that Bootstrap since version 5 do not use `mr` (margin-right) or `ml`(margin-left). They now use `ms` (margin -start) and `me` (margin-end) which takes the flex-direction and direction `ltr`/`rtl` into account. Please post a working [repro] to show where your code stopped working.

Comment: that doesnt work

Comment: then as said above post a [repro]. There is no way to tell you why it is not working if we can reproduce it (which we can't with the tiny piece of code your provided).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```css
/* There is no href destination, so you need to use a style to make the cursor a pointer */

.dropdown-toggle {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <div class="nav">
      <!-- This is essential for the alignment -->
         <ul class="navbar nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
               <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
               <strong>Dropdown</strong>
               </a>
               <!-- Make sure to use "dropdown-menu-end", or else the dropdown will overflow -->
               <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end text-small shadow">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action #1</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action #2</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action #3</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                  </li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#searchbarcontainer" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="searchbar"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
<!-- / Navbar -->
```

What I did there was use the unordered list to make everything inside of it to align to the right. So, if you add anything else to the nav inside of that `ul` it will be right-aligned.

I recommend adding a breakpoint in your css to remove visibility at 233px so that the navbar doesn’t look funky. However, you may also choose to use the `navbar-toggler`.

I will always advise to read the documentation on navbars and spacing by the official Bootstrap team.

Hope this helps!

Further readings:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/spacing/